# MongoSkin Promise query not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoskin

```
var co = require('co');
var MongoClient = require('mongoskin').MongoClient;

var db = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/hellye');
var countries = db.collection('countries', {
    strict: true
});

co(function* () {
    var doc =
        yield countries.find({
            country: 'scotland'
        }).limit(1);
    console.log('> 1');
    console.log(doc);
});

countries.find({
    country: 'scotland'
}).limit(1).next(function (err, doc) {
    console.log('> 2');
    console.log(doc);
});
```

The code above outputs the following in the console:

```
> 2
{ _id: 56b33957a345a53d4c15f6bf,
  country: 'scotland',
  primaryLanguage: 'english' }
```

The first query does not work, why is this? Documentation says it returns a Promise so it should: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#find

Answer (score 0):

`.toArray()` was needed on the end.

```
var doc =
    yield countries.find({
        country: 'scotland'
    }).limit(1).toArray();
```